# Supporting NextJS routing over Spring Boot app without any proxy

Tags: java, spring-boot, routes, next.js

I have created the build for a NextJS app to be served by a Spring Boot application.
The root page / (which is index.html) opens fine, and from there NextJS handles client-side navigation by it's Links, so for example from the root / I can get to /user/edit(which is actually edit.html).

Everthing uptil now is fine. But now if the users decides the reload the page, or tries to open this page by typing/pasting the link. /user/edit will give a 404 as spring only identifies it as /user/edit.html.

I have tried

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    //This works totally fine.
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*.css").addResourceLocations("classpath:static/");
    
    
    //This has not impact.
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**[^.]+$").addResourceLocations("classpath:static/**.html");
  }
}
```

I know the "classpath:static/**.html" doesn't make much sense to resolve. But if it's possible via this approach or anyother approach, that would be much appreciated.
I just need to modify the request path of anything that's not from **/api** and doesn't have an extension to be forworded the the same + '.html'

I don't want to write my own controller to handle serving static content, also I have no SSR so woun't like to use Thymeleaf unless it's the last option, also woudn't want to change all my NextJS routes e.g. /user/edit.html -> /user/edit/index.html.

I've spent many hours searching and trying out different things, I believe Spring is open enough to have this somewhere as a configuration that I don't know of. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I came up with a simple solution. Sharing so it could save time for others.

You need 3 files. Technically you can merge the 1st two into one, but just a bit more cleaner solution.

```java
public abstract class PathForwardHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    abstract protected String provideAlternative(String path);

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        final String alternative = provideAlternative(request.getServletPath());
        if (alternative != null) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher(alternative).forward(request, response);
            return false;
        }
        return HandlerInterceptor.super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
}
```

```java
public class ExtensionAppendInterceptor extends PathForwardHandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    protected String provideAlternative(String path) {
        return ("/".equals(path) || path.contains(".")) ? null : path + ".html";
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new ExtensionAppendInterceptor());
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks - looking for something similar. However I'm trying to convince myself why we need nextjs in the first place. Are you doing this essentially for better bundling of resources as opposed to a giant SPA? I am familiar with spring/jvm but not node/typescript - and considering if I really need to learn the latter to write my app.

Comment: You're welcome. I wanted to support the case when the user wants to refresh the page. For my case most of the code for each page is common so the SPA size will roughly be the same. In my case the requirement was to use Spring, though NextJS is awesome becuase one uses the exact same TypeScript codebase on both the frontend and backend, all in one project, granted if node is choosen as the backend.

Comment: @jasxir , got exactly the same problem with you , i use the nextjs13 app static and put it in spring boot, i can access the route by link but not by direct typing.
Your solution work but i cannot access the spring backend api after that ?any thought?

Comment: @man-man-yu The example code here checks for '.' character, the apis I call didn't have any use of '.'. Can you check if your API call has '.' character? If it does then you'll have to change the code to check for something else.