# Nextjs13 App Directory routing in Sprring Boot Fail

Tags: spring-boot, next.js, next.js13

i got a similar question about this [NextJS routing over Spring Boot app without any proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70394300/supporting-nextjs-routing-over-spring-boot-app-without-any-proxy)

I have the build for a NextJS13 app Direcoty to be served by a Spring Boot application. The root page / (which is index.html) opens fine, and from there NextJS handles client-side navigation by it's Links, so for example from the root / I can get to /user/edit(which is actually edit.html).

But now if the users decides the reload the page, or tries to open this page by typing/pasting the link. /user/edit will give a 404 as spring only identifies it as /user/edit.html.

the user suggest all the path serve by "/" will forward to "/xxx.html" which solve the problem of directing typing the html , however, the backend api/controller endpoint will also be forwarded to page+html.

Answer (score 0):

I found from chinese forum a solution in  2023 by adding interceptors in spring

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
            final var isApiHandle = handler instanceof HandlerMethod;
            final var path = request.getServletPath();
            if (FilenameUtils.getExtension(path).isEmpty() && !"/".equals(path) && !isApiHandle) {
                request.getRequestDispatcher(path + ".html").forward(request, response);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```